# Append variables on page load

Tags: jquery, append

I've been beating my head against the wall trying to get this to work, and I feel like I'm missing something simple.

I have a list of DIVs. Inside each div is a text input. I'm getting the variables from each input, and just want to append it to the end of the div.

Works as expected using a click event, but I want it to append when the page LOADS. :(

Here is my code:

```
$('.myDiv').click(function (){
    var t = $('input:text', this).val();
    $(this).append(t);
});
```

How do I get this to append on page ready or load? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `.click()` to the end:

```
$(function() {
    $('.myDiv').click(function (){
        var t = $('input:text', this).val();
        $(this).append(t);
    }).click();
     //  ^----------invoke the handler on each <div> on page load
});
```

Or if you meant *just* on page load, without the handler, use the [`each()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method to iterate over the elements, running the code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.myDiv').each(function (){
        var t = $('input:text', this).val();
        $(this).append(t);
    });
});
```

Or even a little shorter like this if you're using jQuery 1.4 or later:

```
$(function() {
    $('.myDiv').append(function (){
        return $('input:text', this).val();
    });
});
```

Comment: To explain that a little bit, `.click(function....)` is binding a function to the click event.  `.click();` is then triggering the click event manually.

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I was looking for. .each works for this! Thank You! On to step 2... hehe

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$(document).ready(functon() {
   $('.myDiv').each(function (){
     var t = $('input:text', this).val();
     $(this).append(t);
   }
});
```

This should do what you want without the need to simulate a click.

Answer (score 0):

use `each`  ...

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.myDiv').each(function (){
        var t = $('input:text', this).val();
        $(this).append(t);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$(document).load(function...)
```